# How to make cProfile print only significant functions?

Tags: python, performance, cprofile

I get about 300 entries from my cProfile output and had to scroll up a long time every time I use it.

Is there a way to make cProfile print only like, top 10 lines or something?

Comment: @sam-pyt would you please elaborate?

Comment: the whole point is to show all the different parts of the program, how long it takes to execute, and how often they are executed.

Comment: @sam-pyt but i dont care about functions that are barely executed. I'm sorting my results, hence only the top matters to me.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I sorted by time.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort by say 'cumulative' and show top N lines using **print_stats(4)**. Without sorting on something watching the top N lines may not be of use.

From [Python profiler official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual)

```
import pstats
p = pstats.Stats('restats')
p.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats(10)
```